# Is it able to patch Django thread_sensitive for tests?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, python-asyncio

I use sync_to_async with thread_sensitive=False for async django view like this:

```
@sync_to_async(thread_sensitive=False)
def get_some_from_db():
    ...
```

But in test cases all handlers marked as thread_sensitive=False returns None. Is there any way to patch thread sensitive on True only for tests?